# Can we directly work on Umbraco 4.9.0 Source file(from codeplex) to develop a website Which i opened it using visual studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, umbraco

I already have Umbraco 4.9.0 in my Server so i don't need the source to open installation page. I need to open my default page directly and launch my site.

The problem doing that is every-time when i run the source. It goes too install umbraco i want it too directly open my default page.can it be done by changing  web.config and need to eliminate web.template.config.

I just made the source to skip 3-database step and directly go to 6-Youre Done.But i need too launch my site.I want to launch my site when the source run

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're referring to the fact that when you're building the source, the web.config of the output project gets overwritten, which means you have to do the setup again. If that's the case, then use the 4.10.1 or greater branch, as that fixes the issue with the web.config being overwritten.

As a side note, you shouldn't need to modify/build the source to develop a website in Umbraco, unless you're making modifications to core functionality. You can just get the site setup files rather than the full source and then if you want to edit in Visual Studio, just open the site folder as a website project in VS.Net.

Comment: opening the site in visual studio launches my site too directory lists that all my folders are shown. i dont know where i am going wrong.